# create a file name with the current date & time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, mkdir

I used `datedime` to create a directory name in Python like this:

**Code:**

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

os.mkdir(f"{datetime.now()}")
os.listdir()
```

And when I use `ls` command in terminal, I got the following result:

[image]

And when I got `dir` names with Python:

**Code:**

```py
os.listdir()
```

**Output:**

```py
['.gitlab-ci.yml',
 'public',
 'AUTHORS',
 '.dockerignore',
 'requirements',
 '.git',
 'Dockerfile',
 'manage.py',
 '.editorconfig',
 '2020-01-11 12:53:08.425169',
 'logs',
 '.idea',
 'branch.sh',
 'initial_media',
 'README.md',
 '__pycache__',
 'setup.cfg',
 '.gitignore',
 'venv']
```

**Solution:**

I solved it with `strftime()` method:

**Code:**

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

os.mkdir(f'{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S_%p")}')
```

[image]

---

**TL;DR**

Why single quotes appear in `dir` name? Is it a problem from **datetime** `__str__` or `__repr__` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directory name probably *doesn't* have quotes. It's just displayed that way. Try adding a space to your `strftime` example and see what happens:

```
os.mkdir(f'{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%I %M-%S_%p")}')
```

See [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/12606)